# Different audio quality between Mac Pro and MacBook Pro with the same xcode Release

Tags: xcode, macos, audio, audio-streaming, portaudio

I wrote a program with xcode (using portaudio) on a MacBook Pro (Intel Core 2 Duo 2.66 GHz). The Release works without problem (clear audio streaming) and the CPU Usage Level is almost 90%.
The problem arises when i run the Release on a Mac Pro (Quad Core Intel Xeon 2.8 GHz). The audio stream, when there is a large amount of computation, isn't clear (there are little clicks) despite the use of the CPU is four times lower than the one of MacBook Pro.

I can not understand why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

25% CPU usage in a 4 core system means one core is 100% loaded. Also, I assume the Xeons are Pentium4 Xeons, which have way worse CPU cores than the Core2Duo, even though the clock frequency is a bit higher...

Comment: Looking the CPU Usage Monitor i can see that the 4 cores run in parallel and reach a maximum of 50%. So this quad core has worse performances than the core 2 duo? The clicks are caused by the fact that the portaudio callback function is slower than the filling of the buffer.